# Reset placeholder to default in a Vue JS form after submission

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am wanting to reset the name value in a swatch generator I am building, after the swatch is published, but struggling to get it right. Firstly, all the values in the app, 2 colors and swatch name, are watched and emitted. Here is the name value (`value3`) but the colors are set up the same, just `value1` and `value2` (not resetting the colors)

```
<b-form-input
        id="name"
        size="lg"
        type="text"
        class="search-bar"
        placeholder="Name Your Swatch and Enter to Save"
        v-model="value3"
        ref="value3"
        :value="value3"
        @keypress="publishSwatch"
        >
</b-form-input>
```

and what collects the name is here:

```js
props: ['value'],
```

```js
publishSwatch(e) {
  this.$emit('input', {
    value3: +this.$refs.value3.value,
  });
  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    this.createSwatch();
    this.resetForm(); //Not done yet
    this.handleSwatch();
  }
}
```

the relevant working part of the `createSwatch` function is just:

```js
let name = (`${this.value3}`);  //this works fine to set and output the inputted value
```

```js
resetForm() {
// Stuck for what to put here
}
```

After the swatch is published I want to reset the placeholder to the default in `resetForm()` function, which I can place at the relevant place in `publishSwatch` method, which should be as above, but can't get anywhere near to getting it right. The colors are in another function and not resetting those. I have tried this, but it seems to have no relevance to how the inputs are set up:

```
resetForm() {
    let clear = document.getElementById('name');
    clear.input.value.reset();
}
```

And doesn't work

Tips welcome.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by default placeholder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use `:value` and `v-model` together, because `v-model` creates `:value` automatically so there would be a conflict.
- There is no need for a `ref` because the correct way is to use the `v-model` binding (`value3`) in the instance instead of a DOM value

HTML

```html
<b-form-input
    id="name"
    size="lg"
    type="text"
    class="search-bar"
    placeholder="Name Your Swatch and Enter to Save"
    v-model="value3"
    @keypress="publishSwatch">
</b-form-input>
```

Methods should look like this:

```js
methods: {
  publishSwatch(e) {
    this.$emit('input', {
      value3: +this.value3
    });
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
      this.createSwatch();
      this.resetForm();
      this.handleSwatch();
    }
  },
  resetForm() {
    this.value3 = ''; // <-- Reset the instance value
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/pz14L98r/)

Comment: OK so I dont actually have to use :value and refs, Ill try that thyanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah, refs are good for manipulating the DOM when something can't easily be done with bound values.  For example, setting the focus on a template element.

Comment: Incidentally, had a problem with this, it stopped working,  its looks OIk but doesnt reset the values, any idea why/ Here is current code.

Comment: Had a problem with this, it stopped working,  its looks OIk but doesnt reset the values, any idea why/ Here is current code. data() {
    return {
      value3: null
    }
 },
 methods: {
  // Reset form to default
    resetForm() {
    this.value3 = '';
    if(this.value3 == '') {
      console.log('RESET');
    }
 },    then in function  publishSwatch(e) {
       if (e.key == "Enter") {
       console.log('EMIT');
        this.$emit('input', { value3: +this.value3 });
        this.createSwatch();
        this.resetForm();
        this.handleSwatch();
     }
  }

Comment: It looks like it's been changed to emit only when pressing enter.  It still clears: https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/35p0gmL1